# Overlay View using Frameworks in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a framework (static library) that presents an overlay view on top of the calling delegate. It does so with the following code:

```
[[[self delegate] view] addSubview:overlay.view];
```

I created a basic skeleton app to test it, i.e., the user taps the button and the framework is called. It works perfectly fine in that case.

However, I am trying to implement this in the popular open source iOS game built on cocos-2d, TWEEJUMP. Click [here](https://github.com/haqu/tweejump) for source code of the game.

I want the overlay to be presented as soon as the highscore view is shown to the user. However, Setting the Highscore class as the delegate to my framework causes an error `reason: '-[Highscores view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13d43c70'`

I understand the the Highscore class is not a subclass of UIView, which causes the error. My question is how do you suggest I implement the framework in tweejump. Either the framework that presents the overlay should do it in a different way, or I should call it differently in tweejump.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cocos2d UIView is accessible via

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector].view;
```

In earlier versions it's either `glView` or `openGLView`. You'll have to add the overlay to that view.